# How to make a JFrame stays always on bottom?

Tags: java, jframe

In Java there is this method that make a `JFrame` stays always on top even if you focus in another window:

```
frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

But what about the opposite of this? I need that the frame stays always on bottom, how can I make it?

Comment: I don't understand this requirement. If the frame is always on the bottom, then you would need to iconify all other applications running on the desktop in order to access the frame. I would never use an application like this.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to subclass window, write native hooks (focus listeners) and use it as `native` methods from Java.